# Pentaho mail :- Do not want to display attachment data in mail body.Just want to dispay static message

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Good After noon,

I am using Mail step of Pentaho DI.
I am able to receive mail with attachment files. But I can see those attachment files data and info. in mail body which I do not want.

Can anyone suggest me how to NOT include attachment content in the Body part of email.

Regards,
Nilesh

Comment: if you don't want attachment then don't make any changes in attached files tab.

Comment: I want attachment which I am getting already but in mail Body part also I can see attachment filles content.So, I just want to remove that from Body. I just want to display my static msg in Body and don't want to display attachment file's data in Body.

Comment: how you have designed your transformation..
edit your question by attaching screen shots.

Comment: sorry, But I can't see "Attachment" option in Stack Overflow hence, not able to send you screenshot.

Comment: Hi All, I clicked on "zip files to single archive" and gave name in "Name of zip archive" options. Now, in my email, I can see attachment in zip and attchment data are not showing in mail body comment section. Thanks